# Get value with highest ID in group - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the row with the highest ID from a group, rather than the lowest. I heard you have to do that `JOIN` trick, but it's confusing and I can't get my head around it.

My code so far is this:

```
$userp0l=//userID
$where=//forumID
    SELECT * 
    FROM `noti` 
    WHERE forum='$where' 
    AND user <>  '$userp0l'
    GROUP BY user 
    ORDER BY `id` 
    DESC
```

It works, however it is showing the first entry in the group, rather than the latest. Anyone know how I can rewrite this?

I just said I'd post all of my code, but looking at it, there's not really much else. I run this statement:

```
 $elist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `noti` WHERE forum='$where' AND user <>  '$userp0l' GROUP BY user ORDER BY `id` DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

It gets the information from the database. The information is grouped so I do not capture a user twice when I go to renter data into the table:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($elist) > 0){
while($elist_result = mysql_fetch_array($elist)){
  $shownotir=$elist_result['shownoti']; 
  $userr=$elist_result['user'];
  $forumr=$elist_result['forum'];
    if($shownotir=="n"){
            $pps="INSERT INTO `noti`(`user`, `forum`, `shownoti`, `forumn`, `madeby`) VALUES ('$userr', '$where', '0', '$forumn', '$uu')";
        mysql_query($pps) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    else {
        $pps="INSERT INTO `noti`(`user`, `forum`, `shownoti`, `forumn`, `madeby`) VALUES ('$userr', '$where', '1', '$forumn', '$uu')";
        mysql_query($pps) or die(mysql_error());
    }
     }
    }
```

I need to find if the most recent entry of `shownoti` is a `1` or a `0`. The trouble is, when grouping, it takes the first entry rather than the latest. So if the most recent entry has a `shownoti` value of `0`, but the first entry value has a `1`, it will always show `1` as it is seeing the first entry. I want to order the groups backwards, basically.

Comment: In other words "it doesn't work!" What's that JOIN trick?

Comment: Basically, the answer to this question. I had a little play around with this `JOIN` method, but not managed to achieve anything other than syntax errors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group

Comment: Oh go on, show us what you tried.

Comment: what does `JOIN` has to do anything with selecting highest id from a table?

Comment: @itachi Read the link Gaben gave above and you'll know.

Comment: @GabenNewil Here you have some more examples and ways how to do it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html Hope, it helps.

Comment: @itachi You can also look at the link I provided in comment above.

Comment: I read through the page but that's just baffled me :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)

```
SELECT DISTINCT `user`, `shownoti`
FROM `noti` 
WHERE forum = '97' 
AND user <> '9797'
GROUP BY `user`, `shownoti`
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

You have to remember that 4 (from 420) is greater than 1 (from 1350) so your sorting may have to be a little different. I have created an [example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19cd7/16).

Comment: Just tried and got the same results as though I'd not even used `distinct`. I'm starting to feel as though this is a dead end. I simply just want to get the most recent row of data for each separate `user` value

Comment: I made one more edit to see if you would be closer @GabenNewil. If you could setup a more complete example of your data in SQL Fiddle we could solve the problem.

Comment: The SQL fiddle is great, aside from the fact I don't get all of the data. I really need `shownoti` and `user`, but `shownoti` is not supposed to be distinct :/

Comment: Honestly, I feel we may have hit a dead end. There must be countless ways round this, perhaps creating a second table or something

Comment: I don't know what all the data is related to, so telling you how to normalize it would be a chore. Look at this - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19cd7/16

Comment: Not a clue what you did, but that final fiddle appears to have fixed my problem. Thank you so much¬

Comment: It was all in selecting the right things and then performing the right GROUP BY ....  glad to have helped.